# UICollectionView custom layout invalidate when section count is 0 on viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom layout for uiCollectionView. Now if collectionView has 0 sections. And i push from collectionViewController to another controller and then pop. Now if section count is 0 collectionView will automatically invalidateLayout. How to stop this behaviour.

I have also override shouldInvalidateLayout but it never gets called.